# git highlighting become weird with `zsh-autosuggestions` and `TERM=xterm-256color`

Tags: git, zsh

I installed `zsh-autosuggestions` and enabled 256 color by `export TERM=xterm-256color` in my ZSH, and my git highlighting become weird like the picture showing below. The color of first line is different from the others.

I tried to disable no matter `zsh-autosuggestions` or `TERM=xterm-256color`, the git highlighting become normal(means all color become the same).

Does anybody know what was going go? What can I do to make my git highlighting back to normal?

[image: git st]
[image: git lg]